# C# Dependency injection with partial dbContext classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I have an Entity Framework 5 model, where my `DbContext` is split into two partial files. The `services.AddDbContext()` works and it is injected into the controllers. The problem arises when I want to inject it into my services. They are added using `services.AddScoped()`, but I get the following error:

> Unable to activate type 'MyDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous....

Can't find anything about it. Any help?

Edit:

One partial class/file does not have any constructor. The other one has two, auto generated by the scaffold:

```cs
public MyDbContext(){}

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options){}
```

I must confess, don't know which one is really needed...

Comment: Typically one uses the AddDbContext overload for registration not something from the standard range of singleton,scoped,transient.

Comment: It sounds like you have two or more constructors declared that are interchangeable. Partial classes are little more than split files for a single class definition so I recommend not splitting things like constructor declarations between partial files to avoid obscuring potential problems like this. Find every constructor and remove any that aren't completely necessary. When using dependency injection you generally only need a single constructor declared.

Comment: @Ralf sorry, dont understand what you mean.

Comment: @Steve Py I added some info to my question, have two constructors but in only one partial/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I did not notice the second constructor in `MyService`. Removing one worked.